# In Python Statistics mean and median, how the output type is defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I'm learning python and trying basic functions as creating variables, doing some maths, messing with lists, and using statistics function. However, while experimenting statistics.mean() and statistics.median() I could see a patern of the output variable type.

As two examples, I run the code below twice, just including one element on the list:

```
from statistics import mean, median
z = [10,20,30,40]
x = mean(z)
y = median(z)
print(x)
print(type(x))
print(y)
print(type(y))
```

The output was:

```
25
<class 'int'>
25.0
<class 'float'>
```

Then, I run the code again

```
from statistics import mean, median
z = [10,20,30,40,11]
x = mean(z)
y = median(z)
print(x)
print(type(x))
print(y)
print(type(y))
```

And the output was

```
22.2
<class 'float'>
20
<class 'int'>
```

Is there a rule to know, or a "best practice" to follow and prevent further problemas in the future?

Comment: What *is* the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median

> The median is a robust measure of central location and is less affected by the presence of outliers. When the number of data points is odd, the middle data point is returned:

```
>>> median([1, 3, 5])
3
```

> When the number of data points is even, the median is interpolated by taking the average of the two middle values:

```
>>> median([1, 3, 5, 7])
4.0
```

What this means practically is that `median()` will return a `float` if there are an even number of values. Otherwise it'll return the item from the middle of the list, which could be an `int`.

The [documentation for `mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) just says:

> The arithmetic mean is the sum of the data divided by the number of data points

So, given your results, it looks like `mean` is kept as an `int` unless it has to be a `float`.

If you want to know the specific CPython implementation details, the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5aad027db9618f22f6fa2274e05dd50f928d2ed7/Lib/statistics.py#L295) is available.

Comment: I read the documentation before, but as you showed it is not clear. And when I tested, I didn't realize any pattern. But what you told makes a good rule that seems true. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Eduardo glad I could help. I looked over the source code and it seems pretty straightforward and to match with my interpretation of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of methods in python are written to do the same calculation but with different data types. To me this looks like it interrogates for the faster integer operation first and if this is possible and true returns an int. If this errors it goes for a slower float operation. If you want to force a float return you can use fmean() instead. I don't think median() has a similar option.